# Parse ADO Recordset to Individual Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I'm trying to take an ADO Recordset and then loop through it to parse individual rows to different worksheets within an Excel workbook. Unfortunately, as I step through my code, I get the following error: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. This occurs when I call the sub in my code - it never actually steps into the sub. I'm wondering if I'm somehow not passing the Recordset in correctly or if it's a problem somewhere within my loop.

Regardless, here's my code - any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub SplitData(ByVal rs As ADODB.Recordset)

' Instantiate count variables for each result type
' Start at 2 to give room for Table headers on sheets
Dim NewAppsCount, BadLogCount, MatNotesCount, ZeroBalCount As Integer
NewAppsCount , BadLogCount, MatNotesCount, ZeroBalCount = 2

' Row Counter
Dim Count As Long
Count = 0

' Loop through the recordset and parse rows to appropriate worksheets
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If CStr(rs.Fields("Maturity Date")) = "" Then
        If CStr(rs.Fields("Log_Date")) = "" Then
            ' Applications that have not been properly logged
            Sheet4.Range("A" & CStr(BadLogCount)) = rs.Fields(Count).Value
            Count = Count + 1
            BadLogCount = BadLogCount + 1
        Else
            ' New Applications
            Sheet6.Range("A" & CStr(NewAppsCount)) = rs.Fields(Count).Value
            Count = Count + 1
            NewAppsCount = NewAppsCount + 1
        End If
    Else
        If Month(rs.Fields("Maturity Date")) < Month(Date) Then
            ' Maturing Notes with Zero Outstanding Balance
            Sheet7.Range("A" & CStr(ZeroBalCount)) = rs.Fields(Count).Value
            Count = Count + 1
            ZeroBalCount = ZeroBalCount + 1
        Else
            ' Maturing Notes
            Sheet8.Range("A" & CStr(MatNotesCount)) = rs.Fields(Count).Value
            Count = Count + 1
            MatNotesCount = MatNotesCount + 1
        End If
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Here is the sub that call GetData:

```
Sub GetData(ByVal Update As Boolean)
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Dim path As String
Dim prompt, result As Integer
Dim day, today As String

' ...skipping stuff not related to the issue...

    ' Set the UNC Path
    path = "\\this\is\the\path"

    ' Instantiate ADO Objects
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Connect to data source
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsost.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & path & ";"

    ' The Query
    query = "This is a big 'ol query that I won't repost here"

    'Run the query and populate the Recordset object
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open query, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    'Parse contetns of Recordset to worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Me.SplitData(rs)

    'Close the ADO Objects, set them to null, and exit sub
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Its not clear (to me anyway) which is the line that causing the problem. Or did you post the sub that never gets called.

Comment: This is the sub that may or may not be getting called - it's not exactly clear. My actual call to the sub is in another sub - I just call SplitData(rs). rs is a reference to an ADO recordset I created through a SQL query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing:

```
Me.SplitData(rs)
```

to:

```
Me.SplitData rs
```

Unnecessary parentheses often cause problems in VBA.

(NB I'm assuming that the two `Sub` shown are in a context where `Me` makes sense - e.g. class module, `ThisWorkbook` module, worksheet module, backing a `UserForm` etc)

Comment: Yup - I just figured this out myself. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think that whether or not you use parenthesis determines whether or not the variable is passed ByRef or ByVal. That might not be the only difference though.